# Python pprint issues

Tags: python, pprint

I'm using the [User](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/userclass.html) object from the Google App Engine environment, and just tried the following:

```
pprint(user)
print vars(user)
```

The results:

**pprint(user)**

```
users.User(email='test@example.com',_user_id='18580000000000')
```

**print vars(user)**

```
{'_User__federated_identity': None, '_User__auth_domain': 'gmail.com',
'_User__email': 'test@example.com', '_User__user_id': '1858000000000',
'_User__federated_provider': None}
```

Several issues here (sorry for the multipart):

1. How come I'm not seeing all the variables in my object. It's not showing `auth_domain`, which has a value?
2. Is there a way to have it list properties that are = None? None is a legitimate value, why does it treat those properties like they don't exist?
3. Is there a way to get pprint to line-break between properties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pprint` is printing the `repr` of the instance, while `vars` simply returns the instance's `__dict__`, whose repr is then printed. Here's an example:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self, a, b):
...             self.a = a
...             self.b = b
...     def __repr__(self):
...             return 'Foo(a=%s)' % self.a
...
>>> f = Foo(a=1, b=2)
>>> vars(f)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> pprint.pprint(f)
Foo(a=1)
>>> vars(f) is f.__dict__
True
```

You see that the special method `__repr__` here (called by `pprint()`, the `print` statement, `repr()`, and others) explicitly only includes the `a` member, while the instance's `__dict__` contains both `a` and `b`, and is reflected by the dictionary returned by `vars()`.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple ways to get different line breaks in an object print-dump of this kind.

Sample data:

```
d = dict(a=1, b=2, c=dict(d=3, e=[4, 5, 6], f=dict(g=7)), h=[8,9,10])
```

Standard print with no friendly spacing:

```
>>> print d
{'a': 1, 'h': [8, 9, 10], 'c': {'e': [4, 5, 6], 'd': 3, 'f': {'g': 7}}, 'b': 2}
```

Two possible solutions:

(1) Using `pprint` with `width=1` gives you one leaf node per line, but possibly >1 keys per line:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(d, width=1)
{'a': 1,
 'b': 2,
 'c': {'d': 3,
       'e': [4,
             5,
             6],
       'f': {'g': 7}},
 'h': [8,
       9,
       10]}
```

(2) Using `json.dumps` gives you max one key per line, but some lines with just a closing bracket:

```
>>> import json
>>> print json.dumps(d, indent=4)
{
    "a": 1, 
    "h": [
        8, 
        9, 
        10
    ], 
    "c": {
        "e": [
            4, 
            5, 
            6
        ], 
        "d": 3, 
        "f": {
            "g": 7
        }
    }, 
    "b": 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In reference to question 3, "Is there a way to get pprint to line-break between properties?":

The [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html) make this description:

> The formatted representation keeps objects on a single line if it can, and breaks them onto multiple lines if they don’t fit within the allowed width.

The property "width" (passable in init) is where you specify what is allowable.  I set mine to width=1, and that seems to do the trick.

As an example:

```
pretty = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=2)
```

results in...

```
{ 'acbdf': { 'abdf': { 'c': { }}, 'cbdf': { 'bdf': { 'c': { }}, 'cbd': { }}},
  'cef': { 'abd': { }}}
```

whereas

```
pretty = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=2,width=1)
```

results in...

```
{ 'acbdf': { 'abdf': { 'c': { }},
             'cbdf': { 'bdf': { 'c': { }},
                       'cbd': { }}},
  'cef': { 'abd': { }}}
```

Hope that helps.